# machine learning and model training

Tags: google-colaboratory

I am working on a machine learning project where I am my  training my model on Google Colab. 
I have cloned the repository and model is build up with tensor flow framework.

However, my data-set is too large. Before running the model I have two questions which are coming to mind:

1) If I leave my model overnight to get trained, what is the smartest way to know that my training is completed/left in between? (Any notification through email  . . or ?)

2) What happens, if the internet connection breaks in between

My Google search is not providing me understandable answer. I would appreciate any help with solutions for my queries.

Answer (score 0):

Maximum of 2 instances can be run concurrently and are linked to your Google account. Keep backing up your weights, and re-train if it takes more than 12 hours.

For such long jobs, it's always better to invest in a VPS, but to answer your questions,

1. The maximum lifetime of a job on Colab with the browser open is 12 hours. Therefore, it's a good idea to periodically save your model weights. A script to backup weights while training is a good idea.
2. If the internet connection breaks, the notebook will run for 90 minutes before the instance is considered to be idle and will be recycled. It's similar to closing your browser.